# As of June 2014, what tools should one consider for improving Python code performance?

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a small scientific experiment in Python, and I now need to consider optimizing this code. After profiling, what tools should I consider in order to improve performance. From my understanding, the following wouldn't work:

**Psyco**: out of date (doesn't support Python 2.7)

**Pyrex:** last update was in 2010

**Pypy:** has issues with NumPy

What options remain now apart from writing C modules and then somehow interfacing them with Python (for example, by using **Cython**)?

Comment: As far as I know, `Pypy` is by far best considered to improve speed. If it has issues with `NumPy` I would look into ways to avoid that.

Comment: Note that there is a port of numpy to pypy -- [it's not complete](http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html), but getting there...

Comment: The first task is to identify what parts of the code are slow.  If you're already using Numpy and the Numpy parts are the bottleneck, you may be at or near the end of the line performance-wise.

Comment: Before you plan on alternate interpreters, do the profiling.  Algorithmic changes may be in order first.

Comment: @AShelly Definitely, but I am wondering what one could do *after* the algorithmic changes are done.

Comment: @BrenBarn For sure, but once again, I am assuming that the easiest performance gain steps have been taken: thus, assume that profiling is complete, algorithmic changes have been implemented, and NumPy/SciPy etc. are not the issue.

Comment: @user89: In that case, my basic answer would be "assume it is already as fast as it can be".  I would not count on finding a magic bullet solution that is going to make your Python code faster without any changes to that code.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Careful here.  "as fast as it can be" is usually not the case.  If you find yourself at this point, you need to ask "does it really _need_ to be faster?".  If the answer is (unfortunately) yes, then you need to consider doing _something_ different.  PyPy, Cython/C extensions, new language entirely are all worthwhile experiments with different levels of effort to make it work.  Usually, the goal is to put in the least work to make it "fast enough"...

Comment: @mgilson: I mean "as fast as it can be" within the requirements of the question, which essentially seem to exclude Cython, Pypy, etc.

Comment: @BrenBarn I don't mean to exclude them, as much as provide my current understanding of them. This understanding likely needs to be corrected  in answers/comments.

Comment: There are lots of SO questions about using `Cython` and/or `Numba` with `numpy`.

Comment: maybe gpucomputing with pycuda, if your problem lends itself to such techniques?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Cython to compile the bottlenecks to C. This is very effective for numerical code where you have tight loops. Python loops add quite a lot of overhead, that is non-existent if you can translate things to pure C. In general, you can get very good performance for any statically typed code (that is, your types do not change, and you can annotate them on the source).

You can also write the core parts of your algorithm in C (or take an already written library) and wrap it. You can still do it writing a lot of boilerplate code with Cython or SWIG, but now there are tools like XDress that can do this for you. If you are a FORTRAN person, f2py is your tool.

Modern CPUs have many cores, so you should be able to take advantage of it usin Python's multiprocessing. The guys at joblib have provided a very nice and simplified interface for it.

Some problems are also suitable for GPU computing when you can use PyCUDA.

Theano is a library that is a bridge between Numpy, Cython, Sympy, and PyCUDA. It can evaluate and compile expressions and generate GPU kernels.

Lastly, there is the future, with Numba and Blaze. Numba is a JIT compiler based on LLVM. The development is not complete, as some syntax is missing and bugs are quite common. I don't believe it is ready for production code, unless you are sure your codebase is fully supported and you have a *very* good test coverage. Blaze is a *next generation Numpy*, with support for out of core storage and more flexible arrays; and designed to use Numba as a backend to speed up execution. It is in a quite early stage of development.

Regarding your options:

- **Pysco:** the author considered the project was done, and he decided to collaborate with Pypy. Most of its features are in there now.
- **Pyrex:** abandoned project, where Cython was forked from. It has all its features and much more.
- **Pypy:** not a real option for general scientific code because the interfacing with C is too slow, and not complete. Numpy is only partially suported, and there is little hope Scipy will ever be (mainly because of the FORTRAN dependencies). This may change in the future, but probably not any time soon. Not being able to fully use C extensions limits very much the possibilities for using external code.
  I must add I have used it successfully with Networkx (pure Python networks library), so there are use cases where it could be of use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very informative answer! Could you write a little more explaining this part: > You can use Cython to compile the bottlenecks to C. This is very effective for numerical code where you have tight loops. In general, you can get very good performance for any statically typed code.

Comment: @user89 I have done so. Is it clear now?

Comment: Sort of -- I was wondering if I understood things correctly: Cython can compile (an annotated) Python script into C directly?

Comment: @user89 Sometimes. When you provide enough information (all types, Cython knows all the functions), yes. When you don't, it falls back to the Python layer, with a performance cost. The cool thing is that you start from Python code and build it incrementally into C until it is fast enough, but without having to sacrifice any Python feature.

Comment: Any update on numba now in 2016 compared to pyCUDA? I'm shocked by how hard a time I'm having finding a comparison between the two.
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/overview.html
https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/index.html
Both support GPU programming with what look to be up to date docs so I don't know which is best to go for.

Comment: @DirkHaupt I don't really know, but for GPU I am using Theano now, very nice to use and transparent CPU backend.

Answer (score 2):

[Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) is a JIT compiler for Python code (which works with NumPy). Looks fairly easy, and quite effective.

EDIT: there is a nice example of using Numba to speed up a finite-difference 2D Laplace eq [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jcc242/cfd-python-class/blob/master/lessons/14%20-%20Optimizing%20Loops%20with%20Numba.ipynb)

Comment: Numba is very cool, but a wee unstable. Parts of Python are not yet supported, and some others are buggy.